# How can I update an SQL database table from an XML file?

Tags: sql, xml, database, sql-update

I found an XML file that updates on a daily basic (on the web), and I would like to create a database table from the data in this file, and to have the option to update it, any help?

I'm using Microsoft visual web developer 2010, what should I do?

Comment: It would be nice of you to show [what have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com).

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: I haven't tried anything since I realy don't know how to start, this is the xml file:http://www.boi.org.il/currency.xml , Im using sql server databse (.mdf)

Answer (score 2):

I would store it in a table as follows (with a primary key of your choosing, I'd guess either a surrogate identity column or composite key on currency code and last update):

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Currency
(   
    LastUpdate DATE NOT NULL,
    CurrencyCode CHAR(3) NOT NULL,
    Name NVARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    Unit INT NOT NULL,
    Country NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Rate DECIMAL(10, 4) NOT NULL,
    Change DECIMAL(10, 4) NOT NULL
);
```

Then you can save the file with a store procedure and query the XML with [XQuery](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189075.aspx):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.SaveCurrencyXML @XML XML
AS

    INSERT dbo.Currency (LastUpdate, CurrencyCode, Name, Unit, Country, Rate, Change)
    SELECT  LastUpdate = @XML.value('CURRENCIES[1]/LAST_UPDATE[1]', 'DATE'),
            CurrencyCode = Currency.value('CURRENCYCODE[1]', 'CHAR(3)'),
            Name = Currency.value('NAME[1]', 'NVARCHAR(50)'),
            Unit = Currency.value('UNIT[1]', 'INT'),
            Country = Currency.value('COUNTRY[1]', 'NVARCHAR(50)'),
            Rate = Currency.value('RATE[1]', 'DECIMAL(10, 4)'),
            Change = Currency.value('CHANGE[1]', 'DECIMAL(10, 4)')
    FROM    @XML.nodes('CURRENCIES/CURRENCY') c (Currency);
    GO
```

Although if you do use a composite key you will need to use MERGE:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.SaveCurrencyXMLMERGE @XML XML
AS
    WITH C AS
    (   SELECT  LastUpdate = @XML.value('CURRENCIES[1]/LAST_UPDATE[1]', 'DATE'),
                CurrencyCode = Currency.value('CURRENCYCODE[1]', 'CHAR(3)'),
                Name = Currency.value('NAME[1]', 'NVARCHAR(50)'),
                Unit = Currency.value('UNIT[1]', 'INT'),
                Country = Currency.value('COUNTRY[1]', 'NVARCHAR(50)'),
                Rate = Currency.value('RATE[1]', 'DECIMAL(10, 4)'),
                Change = Currency.value('CHANGE[1]', 'DECIMAL(10, 4)')
        FROM    @XML.nodes('CURRENCIES/CURRENCY') c (Currency)
    )
    MERGE dbo.Currency cu
    USING C 
        ON C.LastUpdate = cu.LastUpdate
        AND C.CurrencyCode = cu.CurrencyCode
    WHEN MATCHED AND 
                C.Name != cu.Name 
            OR  C.Unit != cu.Unit
            OR  C.Country != cu.Country
            OR  C.Rate != cu.Rate
            OR  C.Change != cu.Change
        THEN UPDATE
        SET Name = C.Name,
            Unit = C.Unit,
            Country = C.Country,
            Rate = C.Rate,
            Change = C.Change
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT (LastUpdate, CurrencyCode, Name, Unit, Country, Rate, Change)
        VALUES (C.LastUpdate, C.CurrencyCode, C.Name, C.Unit, C.Country, C.Rate, C.Change);
```

Then you can simply call your procedures to save your data:

```
DECLARE @X XML = '<CURRENCIES>
                    <LAST_UPDATE>2014-01-30</LAST_UPDATE>
                    <CURRENCY><NAME>Dollar</NAME><UNIT>1</UNIT><CURRENCYCODE>USD</CURRENCYCODE><COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY><RATE>3.492</RATE><CHANGE>0.057</CHANGE></CURRENCY>
                    <CURRENCY><NAME>Pound</NAME><UNIT>1</UNIT><CURRENCYCODE>GBP</CURRENCYCODE><COUNTRY>Great Britain</COUNTRY><RATE>5.7575</RATE><CHANGE>-0.312</CHANGE></CURRENCY>
                    <CURRENCY><NAME>Yen</NAME><UNIT>100</UNIT><CURRENCYCODE>JPY</CURRENCYCODE><COUNTRY>Japan</COUNTRY><RATE>3.4087</RATE><CHANGE>0.383</CHANGE></CURRENCY><CURRENCY><NAME>Euro</NAME><UNIT>1</UNIT><CURRENCYCODE>EUR</CURRENCYCODE><COUNTRY>EMU</COUNTRY><RATE>4.7492</RATE><CHANGE>-0.204</CHANGE></CURRENCY>
                    <CURRENCY><NAME>Dollar</NAME><UNIT>1</UNIT><CURRENCYCODE>AUD</CURRENCYCODE><COUNTRY>Australia</COUNTRY><RATE>3.0620</RATE><CHANGE>0.219</CHANGE></CURRENCY>
                    <CURRENCY><NAME>Dollar</NAME><UNIT>1</UNIT><CURRENCYCODE>CAD</CURRENCYCODE><COUNTRY>Canada</COUNTRY><RATE>3.1225</RATE><CHANGE>-0.24</CHANGE></CURRENCY>
                    <CURRENCY><NAME>krone</NAME><UNIT>1</UNIT><CURRENCYCODE>DKK</CURRENCYCODE><COUNTRY>Denmark</COUNTRY><RATE>0.6365</RATE><CHANGE>-0.188</CHANGE></CURRENCY>
                    <CURRENCY><NAME>Krone</NAME><UNIT>1</UNIT><CURRENCYCODE>NOK</CURRENCYCODE><COUNTRY>Norway</COUNTRY><RATE>0.5602</RATE><CHANGE>-0.568</CHANGE></CURRENCY>
                    <CURRENCY><NAME>Rand</NAME><UNIT>1</UNIT><CURRENCYCODE>ZAR</CURRENCYCODE><COUNTRY>South Africa</COUNTRY><RATE>0.3099</RATE><CHANGE>-1.054</CHANGE></CURRENCY>
                    <CURRENCY><NAME>Krona</NAME><UNIT>1</UNIT><CURRENCYCODE>SEK</CURRENCYCODE><COUNTRY>Sweden</COUNTRY><RATE>0.5378</RATE><CHANGE>-0.407</CHANGE></CURRENCY>
                    <CURRENCY><NAME>Franc</NAME><UNIT>1</UNIT><CURRENCYCODE>CHF</CURRENCYCODE><COUNTRY>Switzerland</COUNTRY><RATE>3.8827</RATE><CHANGE>0.072</CHANGE></CURRENCY>
                    <CURRENCY><NAME>Dinar</NAME><UNIT>1</UNIT><CURRENCYCODE>JOD</CURRENCYCODE><COUNTRY>Jordan</COUNTRY><RATE>4.9370</RATE><CHANGE>0.032</CHANGE></CURRENCY>
                    <CURRENCY><NAME>Pound</NAME><UNIT>10</UNIT><CURRENCYCODE>LBP</CURRENCYCODE><COUNTRY>Lebanon</COUNTRY><RATE>0.0232</RATE><CHANGE>0</CHANGE></CURRENCY>
                    <CURRENCY><NAME>Pound</NAME><UNIT>1</UNIT><CURRENCYCODE>EGP</CURRENCYCODE><COUNTRY>Egypt</COUNTRY><RATE>0.5016</RATE><CHANGE>0.06</CHANGE></CURRENCY>
                </CURRENCIES>';

EXECUTE dbo.SaveCurrencyXML @X;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0ca7b/3)**

---

**ADDENDUM**

I assume when you say you are inserting with:

```
Insert into History values('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}')", date, id, "Deposit", amount, curr
```

You are actually using `String.Format`, i.e.:

```
var sql = String.Format("Insert into History values('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}')", date, id, "Deposit", amount, curr);
```

If so **PLEASE STOP IMMEDIATELY**. This is really bad practise, it not only makes you vunerable to [SQL injection](http://bobby-tables.com/), it also forces recompilation of the query every time as it is unable to make use of [cached query plans](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181055%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).
Another downside is that it is not strongly typed, in your query, assuming `date` is of the `DateTime` type, you automatically call the `ToString()` method on this, which will return a string dependant on the culture info of the thread calling it, there is no guarantee the output string will be in a format that the database recognises as a date time, so if your destination column is a datetime you will get a conversion error.

Instead you should use parameterised queries, but first, although I suspect you may also have shortened your query for example purposes, but it is always a good idea to [explicitly state the column list](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list) when inserting, so your final query would become:

```
var sql = "INSERT History (Date, Id, Deposit, Amount, Curr) VALUES (@Date, @Id, @Deposit, @Amount, @Curr);";
```

You then need to add your parameters to your `SqlCommand`, e.g.

```
var date = DateTime.Now;
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", date);
```

This means that when sent to the DB the query will treat `@Date` as a DateTime (because the value passed was a datetime) meaning your query is much more type safe.

So for your example, to call the stored procedures above you would use something like:

```
//using System.Xml;
//using System.Data.SqlClient;
//using System.Data.SqlTypes;

XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
xmldoc.Load(@"YourXMLFile.xml");
using (var connection = new SqlConnection("ConnectionString"))
using (var command = new SqlCommand("dbo.SaveCurrencyXML", connection))
{
    var xml = new SqlXml(new XmlTextReader(xmldoc.InnerXml, XmlNodeType.Document, null));
    var param = new SqlParameter("@XML", SqlDbType.Xml).Value = xml;
    command.Parameters.Add(param);
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try this as soon as i can

Comment: First of all I want to thank you again for your great help, but i can't manage to understand this, In my class we are using microsoft web developer in c# and when we work with querys such as "Insert into History values('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}')", date, id, "Deposit", amount, curr .      So where should i write what you gave me?